# Complie error: Expected Separator or )

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, vba

I'm attempting to make a macro to insert a formula into a cell range that references a table on the page, but I'm getting the compile error. Can anyone give me a hand with this? It doesn't seem to like that I'm referencing a Table (or the @Duration part anyways, but this is necessary). I basically just need it to drop this formula string into the required cells.

Code:

```
Range("A2:A100").Formula = MID(Table4[@Duration],FIND("m",Table4[@Duration],1)-1,7)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the formula needs to be in quotes:

```
Range("A2:A100").Formula = "=MID(Table4[@Duration],FIND(""m"",Table4[@Duration],1)-1,7)"
```

Comment: @Jarvis595 Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.